# I'm building a deep neural network and I keep getting "TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Tags: tensorflow, keras, sequential

I'm trying to develop a deep neural network where I want to predict a single parameter based on multiple inputs. However, I'm getting the error, as stated in the title, and I'm not sure why. I haven't even called an `__init__()` method in my code, so I'm confused as to why it's giving me this error.

This is the code that I've written so far and yields the following error. I would appreciate any help, thanks!

````
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = pd.read_csv(r"AirfoilSelfNoise.csv")
x = d.iloc[:, 0:5] #frequency [Hz], angle of attack [deg], chord length [m], free-stream velocity [m/s], suction side displacement thickness [m], input
y = d.iloc[:, 5] #scaled sound pressure level [dB], output
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['f', 'alpha', 'c', 'U_infinity', 'delta', 'SSPL'])

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

mod = keras.Sequential(
    keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
)

mod.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
mod.fit(xtrain, ytrain, epochs=50)```

TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add brackets into the `Sequential` function. With your code, it takes all the layers as different input parameters. However, the first parameter needs to be a list of your desired layers. In your case:

```
mod = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(30, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(25, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')]
)
```